# How to convert a connection to a pool connection in MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, mysql-workbench

I. I made the code below but I recently learned about pool connection, which according to what I read are better. I just don't understand how to export the connection to a different file. So, if you could guide me on how to do it I would appreciate it. Thanks.

connection.js:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
 
const con = mysql.createConnection({
      host:'127.0.0.1', // host of server
      user:'root', // MySQL user
      password:'BLABLABLA', // MySQL password
      database: "rpg"
    });
    
exports.con = con
```

database.js:

```
const con = require('./connection').con;

mp.events.add('playerJoin', (player) => {
    con.query('INSERT INTO BLA BLA BLA', function (err, result) {
//ETC ETC
```

Basically, I want to know how to export, import and make a query. I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for creating a pool is very similar to the code you have right now. The only difference is there's the extra step of requesting a connection from the pool.

connection.js

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: "localhost",
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  database: "rpg"
});


exports.pool = pool;
```

database.js

```js
const pool = require("./connection").pool;

// Ask the pool for a connection
pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if(err){
    
        // Do something with the error
  
    } else {
  
        // Do something with the connection and release it after you're done
        conn.query('INSERT INTO BLA BLA BLA', (err, rows) => {
            // Do something with the result

            // release the connection after you're done so it can be reused
            conn.release();
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you. I only have a doubt. Is conn.query a mistake? Should it be pool.query? If not, where do I define conn? Thanks!

Comment: Nope, conn is the connection itself. A pool is just a group of connections and so you ask it for a connection and then use that connection to perform your query. The conn variable is a parameter in the callback for pool.getConnection

Comment: Ahh! I missed that. Thanks!